# mod_rewrite use in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache2.4, mod-rewrite

Okay, so there are plenty of threads on how to use mod_rewrite, but I find it seems to work a bit differently in Apache 2.4. I tried this:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/vhosts/example.com
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

This is situated in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/httpd.conf/`, and I've runt `sudo a2enconf httpd.conf` which worked and enabled it, but it doesn't want to work anyways..

I tried it without the `Directory` bit, I tried calling it `mod_rewrite.c` which wordpress suggests, but neither of the above seems to work. I also tried it with the `Directory` tag but without `IfModule`, which for obvious reasons ended up with Apache not starting.. And yes, I restart Apache between every attempt.

Is there a new trick to this in Apache 2.4 that I don't know if? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` installed? `a2enmod rewrite`.

Comment: Nope. Module mod_rewrite does not exist. How do I solve that then?

Comment: Yeah, I found that just now, thankyou. How should I write the httpd.conf to get it to work, then?

Comment: Okay, so a friend of mine, pretty good at this, tells me it wont work if I put it in the httpd.conf, it has to be in a .htaccess to function. Issue is, I got the module running, have removed it from the httpd.conf and made a .htaccess, but it wont work anyways. What now?

Comment: What is the output of `ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Answer (score 11):

After **enabled mod_rewrite** by this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Make file for your **httpd configuration** in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/** so in my Ubuntu the file that I make is **/etc/apache2/sites-available/code-machine.conf**:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Edit**: 
And as reminded by Chris Gregory and firepol, you can **register** the new configuration file **code-machine.conf**:

```
sudo a2ensite code-machine.conf
```

Then **restart your apache**:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: As Chris Gregory reminded, register the new config file, in this case the code-machine.conf (I called it differently so adapt to your conf file): sudo a2ensite code-machine.conf

Then: sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 2):

even I was facing a similar issue with Apache 2.4 on 14.04

Please note, the configuration file is now located at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

I tried this and it worked out for me.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Locate the directive Directory where your root directory is located and set the following:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 2):

I had **register** the new conf file with Apache before it would work.

```
sudo a2ensite MyConfiguration.conf
```

Then I could run

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```